# How to add a method to core class by gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

To add a method to core class I created a blank gem by:

```
bundle gem my_gem
```

Then edit a `.gemspec` and create a `lib/my_gem/core_ext/array.rb` file.

```
module MyGem::CoreExt::Array
  def foo
    p 'foo'
  end
end

class Array
  include MyGem::CoreExt::Array
end
```

Then I require the file from `lib/my_gem.rb`.

```
require 'my_gem/core_ext/array.rb'
```

And then by `bundle exec irb`

```
> MyGem
=> MyGem
> [1,2,3].foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for [1, 2, 3]:Array
> MyGem::CoreExt::Array
NameError: uninitialized constant MyGem::CoreExt
```

I understand the file is not loaded, how can I load the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you're defining your module here: `module MyGem::CoreExt::Array` since you can't define `MyGem::CoreExt::Array` when `MyGem::CoreExt` doesn't exist.

**my_gem/core_ext/array.rb**

```
module MyGem
  module CoreExt
    module Array
      def foo
        p 'foo'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or, simply define `MyGem::CoreExt` before `MyGem::CoreExt::Array`:

```
module MyGem::CoreExt
end

module MyGem::CoreExt::Array
  def foo
    p 'foo'
  end
end

class Array
  include MyGem::CoreExt::Array
end
```

**In IRB**

```
require 'my_gem'

[].foo  # Should output 'foo'
```